# Networking two computers for homegroup

Tags: windows, networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I have a wireless high speed Internet connection, using a wireless network adapter on my PC (Windows 8.1 x64), that I want to share with other computers and laptops in my home (also Windows 8.1).  I want to have a home group with them at the same time.  The reason why I'm trying to create a home group between computers is more than just sharing files or folders.

I think one of the requirements for having a home group with multiple computers is that they must be in the same subnet (e.g., 192.168.1.x).  So far I've tried many ways but I could only share the Internet with other computers and not the home group.  The other computers have IP addresses like 192.168.137.42 that weren't in the same subnet with my PC.  My PC is getting a static IP address (192.168.1.5), from the wireless network adapter.

Additionally, I have a TP-Link wireless dual-band DSL modem/router/switch and a wireless network adapter that I'm not using, that are available to use with this network.

How can I network computers in my home to have a home group and also share Internat access?

**UPDATE:**

Other computers have both wired and wireless network adapters and the router/switch/modem I mentioned can be used too.

**Second Question:**
When i try to bridge the wireless network that has Internet with the Ethernet network adapter that has no internet, Windows doesn't bridge them and disables the Ethernet.  How can I fix this?

If I bridge them, they will be in the same subnet.   Would I then be able to connect my router's LAN/WAN port to the Ethernet port and share the Internet?

Comment: Can you please verify your hardware set up a little more clearly? It sounds like you have a wireless modem/router which is giving wireless access to a workstation. Does that workstation have a second wireless adapter card or just one? How are the other computers connected/networked. Do they have a wired connection or wireless cards?

Comment: My PC is getting wireless Internet from another network and as I'm using a usb wireless network adapter, i can't use my wireless router/modem to share it with other computers, so the Internet first comes to my PC. other computers in my home are not currently connected or networked, I'm asking how to do that.

Comment: Do any of the other computers have wireless cards or Ethernet adapters? You will need to connect them in some fashion, do you have a switch and cables?

Comment: Yeah i have all of them. other computers have both wired and Wireless network adapters, i have a Wireless router/switch/modem and cables.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to share the internet connection via one system when you can directly connect those devices to your router? I think you should set your router to dynamic IP that way, any device trying to get access to the internet, will be allocated an IP by the router and everything should work fine... And the homegroup has got nothing to do with sharing internet in that case... Best of luck!

Comment: How do you connect a USB wireless network adapter to a router?

Comment: If your adapter is rightly installed in system then it should be scanning for available routers, just click on the network icon in the bottom right of the screen in windows and if everything goes right then you must be able to see your router listed. Then you can connect to it. Incase you can't see the adapter of available connections then go to hardware and devices the scan for the hardware changes.

Comment: I see my router but i don't really understand what you're saying

Comment: Which device are you referring to as "WIreless Adapter"?

Comment: Wireless network adapter like [these](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/?categoryid=3957)

Comment: If you can see the router then then why can't you connect to it?

Comment: How on earth do you connect to a router?

Comment: The way you connect to wifi on a laptop.

Comment: Why should i want to connect to the router when it has no Internet?! I'm trying to give Internet to the router.

Comment: Okay, sorry now i got your point.